# MySQL - How to find records for yesterday when timestamp is part of date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

My MySQL table stores records with a date/time stamp.  I am wanting to find records from the table that were created yesterday (as in have a creation date of yesterday - regardless of what the timestamp portion is)

Below is what a db record looks like:

[image]

I have tried the following select (and a few other variations, but am not getting the rows with yesterday's date.

```
SELECT m.meeting_id, m.member_id, m.org_id, m.title 
  FROM meeting m
 WHERE m.create_dtm = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Not exactly sure how I need to structure the where clause to get meeting ids that occurred yesterday.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your query matches only the time at midnight yesterday! You'll need a range...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach would truncate the creation timestamp to date, then compare:

```
where date(m.create_dtm) = current_date - interval 1 day
```

But it is far more efficient to use half-open interval directly against the timestamp:

```
where m.create_dtm >= current_date - interval 1 day and m.create_dtm < current_date
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had thought about your first suggestion, but am glad there was a more efficient method.  Thank you so much GMB!

Comment: ...with appropriate indexes

Answer (score 0):

You can try next queries:

```
SELECT 
    m.meeting_id, m.member_id, m.org_id, m.title, m.create_dtm
FROM meeting m
-- here we convert datetime to date for each row
-- it can be expensive for big table
WHERE date(create_dtm) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);

SELECT 
    m.meeting_id, m.member_id, m.org_id, m.title, m.create_dtm
FROM meeting m
-- here we calculate border values once and use them
WHERE create_dtm BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 SECOND);
```

Here live fiddle: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1e8cb7a384f19e7c45e258aec4908717&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)